Unhandled Exception when using Roslyn
I used Roslyn to compile a file, and it did successfully compiled. But the outpot .exe file thrown a unhandled exception:
未经处理的异常:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 未能加载文件或程序集“System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e”或它的某一个依赖项。系统找不到指定的文件。

And I checked the references, there is a System.Private.CoreLib.dll indeed.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Private.CoreLib.dll
C:\Users\Eren\Pictures\Codes\RoslynTest\RoslynTest\bin\x64\Release\net8.0\RoslynTest.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Runtime.dll
C:\Users\Eren\Pictures\Codes\RoslynTest\RoslynTest\bin\x64\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Collections.Immutable.dll
C:\Users\Eren\Pictures\Codes\RoslynTest\RoslynTest\bin\x64\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Collections.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Console.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Linq.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Threading.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Memory.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Security.Cryptography.dll

Here is my source code, and the file to compile is a simple calculate
then print function.

string sourceCode = File.ReadAllText(sourceFilePath);

var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
Console.WriteLine(syntaxTree);

var compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication);

var references = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Location))
    .Select(a => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(a.Location))
    .ToList();

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
    assemblyName: "RoslynTest",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
    references: references,
    options: compilationOptions
);

string outputPath = Path.Combine(@"D:\RoslynTest\", "RoslynTest.exe");

EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(outputPath);```

